# Convert data:image/png;base64 into an image type in database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, canvas, base64

So here is the scenario. I have a canvas and I am getting its data via

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

and i will put the data into a TextArea so i could insert it into database

```
 document.getElementById("TextArea1").textContent = image
```

If i will insert the data inside the textarea, the "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN..." into the database, it says that

```
Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with image.
```

So, i what i want and what i need to do is to convert the "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN..." into something like "0x89504E470D0A1A0A..." when inserting it into database. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is in Base64 format which is a string, you need to convert that first to a byte array in order to save it in your database. Something like this:

```
Dim base64String = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Temp\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(@Image)"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
Dim p As New SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Image)
p.Value = imageBytes
cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

More exmaples here on loading and saving images to database:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437937/Save-and-Retrieve-Image-from-a-SQL-Server-Database

Comment: I am using asp.net sir, im sorry i forgot to put it in the tag. I have an error. "fromstream is not a member of system.web.ui.webcontrols.image"

Comment: Updated the answer with a fuller solution

Comment: I think its now working! But i have a question. My data is like "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA..." But i only need the "iVBORw0KGgoAAAA..." part. What will i do?

Comment: Look at the `String.Replace` method to remove the part you don't want. If you can't figure this out then start a new question

Answer (score 0):

You are entering text in DB and your db field type is image so you are getting error. If possible then change your db field type to varchar it will work.

Comment: it's not possible because i already have a lot of data which is in that db field.